# Print out last line and then run program again Y/N

Tags: c++

I am stuck on this random guessing game for school.

[image]

I have added the code that needed to be added, but the console keeps closing without returning the last strings.

I would also like to learn how to make the program run again with clicking `Y` to run again.

I am still learning C++, so any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
// GuessingGameApp.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>//added to run string
#include <locale>//added toupper run again

using namespace std;    

int main()
{
    //Seed the random number generator
    srand(time(0));
    int selectedNumber = rand() % 20 + 1; int numberOfTries = 0;
    int inputtedGuess;
    std::cout << "Guess My Number Game\n\n";
    //Ask the user for a value until the correct number is entered
    do {
        std::cout << "Enter a guess between 1 and 20:";
        std::cin >> inputtedGuess;
        ++numberOfTries;
        if (inputtedGuess > 20 || inputtedGuess < 1) {
            cout << "Your guess is out of range.\n\n";
        }
        else if (inputtedGuess > selectedNumber) {
            cout << "Too high!\n\n";
        }
        else if (inputtedGuess < selectedNumber) {
            cout << "Too low!\n\n";
        }
    }
    while (inputtedGuess != selectedNumber);

    //Congratulate the user and end the program
    std::cout << "\nCongratulations! You solved it in " << numberOfTries << "   tries!\n" << std::endl;

    //fix problem with console closing and (add "play again" option), so I can 
    //learn
    //printf; did not work... Break did not work..
    //

    return 0;
}
```

I was able to get the console to stay open by putting a `break` at line 33, but I want to learn how to do this correctly so I deleted the `break`.

Comment: if you have `using namespace std;` which you do, you do not need to to use `std::` in front of of `std::cout` and `std::cin`, you can just use `cout` and `cin`.

Comment: Eeek, please take a bit of care to *format your code* in a readable fashion. I'd never accept this mess in any code base I'm involved in.

Comment: Use an outer *do while* loop...

Comment: Well, you know how a do-while loop works, you need one more.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, that is how the code landed when I copied and pasted into the post question box. I used the ctrl K to indent but when it posted it posted that!!

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant I will add one more.

Comment: Thank you @Jarod42 I will try that.

Comment: @user7999687 read StackOverflow's documentation for how to format text. Especially code, sometimes you have to reformat it manually to make it nice.

Comment: Thank you @RemyLebeau for fixing it for me.. I will read how to do this correctly in the future. :)

Answer (score 1):

The last line of your output should actually be printed. The reason why the last line "is not printed" is probably that your IDE closes the console before you can see the final output (though it should be there). Many IDEs allow to make the console visible after program termination. BTW: Note that when pasting the code you probably lost a `<<` before `std::endl` in `std::cout << "\nCongratulations! You solved it in " << numberOfTries << " tries!\n" std::endl;` But this has actually to be a copy-paste problem, because your program would not have compiled otherwise.

Anyway, by providing a "Try again?"-logic, your program does not terminate and the problem is solved.

I'd suggest to provide a separate function performing the guess, which is then called in a do-while loop with the `"Try again="`-question.

```
void guess() {
   // your code (except srand) goes here...
}

int main() {

    srand(time(0));  //Seed the random number generator only once

    char doAgain;
    do {
        guess();
        cout << "Try again (Y/N)?";
        cin >> doAgain;
    }
    while (toupper(doAgain)=='Y');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Stephan I added the do and while but the console still closes after the the correct number is guessed.

Answer (score 0):

As people suggested, you can add another do-while loop to repeat the game.

```
int choice = 0;

do {
  // first part of code..

  do { 
     // inner do-while
  } while (inputtedGuess != selectedNumber);

  std::cout << "\nCongratulations! You solved it in " << numberOfTries << " tries!\n" std::endl; 

  cout << "\nWould you like to play again?\n\n";
  cout << "1 - Yes\n";
  cout << "2 - No\n\n";

  cout << "Choice: ";
  cin >> choice;

} while(choice == 1);
```

Comment: I finally got the console to stay opened by adding... system("pause");
 printf("Press any key to continue...\n"); _getch();This seemed to work when just adding system("pause"); and Printf on there own would not work, but writing both lines of code made it work. :)